# Trying to render an emission layer with environment reflections on transparent background in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, layers, compositing-nodes

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I am making a rendering for a video wall during a live performance coming up, and what I am trying to achieve is two separate renders;

1. the background/environment, unaffected by the pink "Laser Bridge" and its emission reflections,
2. and the laser bridge itself with its pink reflections on transparency that can then be overlayed over #1.

I have done a lot of learning of how to composite render layers and such, but given I am no expert, I am looking for advice.

I illustrate what I am trying to achieve in the diagram below. The three colored layers represent layer #2 (only separated by color to indicate what I will be doing in my live performance, shifting the hue of the laser and its reflections on the environment, thus why I am trying to render it out separately)

The gray layer represents layer #1, which also contains the white emissive environment lights you see in the two renderings below.

[image]

This is the environment layer with the white emission textures on the lights as you can see. I am not done texturing the scene but I wanted to get this problem out of the way before I continued.

[image]

Below is what the final thing should look like when I overlay both the environment layer and the laser and its reflections in my live performance

[image]

I have not found any solutions, and I am probably making it sound more convoluted than it is, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Bump? Is that a thing?